# Proof verification that the exterior measure of a cube is equal to its volume?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

[image]

Taken from Stein and Shakarchi. Why must we use the whole $\epsilon$ argument (below the black line). Wouldn't the following much simpler proof show $|Q| \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty |Q_j|$?

We've previously proven a lemma that states if $R, R_1, ..., R_N$ are rectangles, and $R \subseteq \cup_{j=1}^\infty R_j$, then
$$
|R| \leq \sum_{j=1}^N |R_j|.
$$

This is for finite $N$, but since each $|R_j|$ is positive, this must hold for an infinite collection of rectangles as well. Therefore, the claim that
$$
|Q| \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty |Q_j|
$$

follow immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't follow immediately because in order to use the lemma, we need a *finite* covering of $Q$. That's how compactness of $Q$ enter the picture.

From $Q\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty Q_j$ we can't deduce that $Q\subseteq\bigcup_{j\in J}Q_j$ for a finite index set $J$.

Comment: I see. Thanks!!